# Adding and removing views from UIScrollView on iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, viewpage

I'm trying to implement a view pager using horizontal UIScrollView. The view pager may contain many views. I'm using UIScrollview with `pagingEnabled` to true. The problem is that I cannot have all the views in the memory at the same time as there can be around 40-50 different views. So I decided to load the current view and its adjacent 3 views on both sides (right and left). When I scroll then using `scrollViewDidScroll` method I remove a view from the left and insert a new view to the right. For doing this I do the following:

- First, check whether the scroll is right scroll or left then if a complete page is scrolled or not.
- Then (for the right scroll) I remove the left most view from superView (i.e. is scrollView).
- Move the x co-ordinate of remaining views to the left.
- Add a new subview to the right.
- Change the content size of the scroll view accordingly.

Somehow the above implementation is not working properly, especially the one involving changing the x co-ordinates. I think that I'm missing something and trying to solve the problem of manipulating views within scrollView in the wrong manner. This is the [link](https://github.com/shahankit/PageViewScrollView.git) to the demo project that I implemented on GitHub. Please any help regarding problems in the current implementation or any other idea as to how to implement it another way is very much welcome.

**NOTE:** This code has one more bug already while swiping on the right from the first view to the second view which happens sometimes. I couldn't find any solution to that either. The stack trace of that problem is [here](http://pastebin.com/FqfEL7yx).

Comment: Why do you need to shift the x-coordinates?  The coordinates should remain fixed.  With each page-swipe you should only need to remove a view from the end, and calculate the coordinates for the opposite end and add the new view there.

Comment: But that would leave an empty space at first position. Thus there would be blank space of scroll view background color at the left most position during moving right.

Comment: Don't remove it until the scrolling has stopped.  That position is off-screen.  Plus you said you have a buffer of 3 views on either side, which are also off-screen.

Comment: I only remove them after scrolling by a particular offset. And the particular offset if equal to page width or screen width in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so actually the approach of shrinking and expanding scrollView content size is not the correct approach (at least in my scenario). As I already the number of views will remain fixed, I set the contentSize fixed to number of views * screen width. Now each time I just use `removeFromSuperview()` to remove them from scrollView and add a new one to scrollView in `scrollViewDidScroll()` method.

The complete working project is updated [here](https://github.com/shahankit/PageViewScrollView).